# Using R and XLConnect to read Excel time

Tags: r, excel, xlconnect

I am using R to read an Excel file that contains two columns with times in 12hr format
 test.xlsx => `A1: 1:40:50 p.m.   A2: 00:00:00 a.m.`.

I have installed the XLConnect package to read the file so I scripted this:

```
library(XLConnect)
a <- readWorksheetFromFile("test.xlsx",sheet=1, header=F)
```

What I get from this is:

```
                   Col1                  Col2
1   1899-12-31 12:24:02   1899-12-30 22:43:12
```

These time values are not the same as the ones in Excel.  After struggling a while with R I came with the following solution:

```
t <- as.POSIXct((as.numeric(a[1,1])-as.numeric(b))
                ,origin = "1900-01-01 00:00:00",tz="UCT")
print(t)
[1] "1900-01-01 13:40:50 UCT"
```

Which is equal to the time in cell A1.

My question is: **Is there a simpler way to import times (not date time) from Excel ?**

Comment: I can't replicate - perhaps an issue with your source data?

Comment: I created a new Excel file and set the first cell to `1:40:50 p.m.`, and then set its format to Time (format cell). Same with the second cell.

Comment: As did I.  Works as it should on my end. `a <- readWorksheetFromFile("test.xlsx",sheet=1, header=F); str(a); $ Col1: POSIXct, format: "1899-12-31 13:40:50" "1899-12-31 00:00:00"`

Comment: The 'chron' package has a time-class but otherwise it's generally better to stick with `POSIXct`-class which is datetime,.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21312173/how-can-i-retrive-the-time-only-with-xlconnect

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to extract the time directly with the following code. This approach works only on Windows.

```
library(RDCOMClient)

dir_Path <- "D:\\"
excel_File <- "test_Res.xlsx"
path_Excel_File <- paste0(dir_Path, excel_File)

xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE
xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_Excel_File)
Sheets <- xlWbk$Sheets() 
nb_Sheets <- Sheets$count() 

list_DF_By_Sheet <- list()

for(l in 1 : nb_Sheets)
{
  mat <- matrix(NA, nrow = 1, ncol = 2)
  
  for(i in 1 : 1)
  {
    for(j in 1 : 2)
    {
      mat[i, j] <- Sheets[[l]]$Cells(i,j)$Text()    
    }
  }
  
  list_DF_By_Sheet[[l]] <- mat
}

list_DF_By_Sheet

[[1]]
     [,1]      [,2]     
[1,] "1:40:50" "0:00:00"
```